# .js, .jpg files link to .html pages

Tags: php, javascript, jpeg

In some pages I have seen (like those of GitHub and Wikipedia), there are some links that end in `.js`, `.jpg` etc. which means clicking them should show me the JS file or the image (and so on). But, as we all know, they display a page (the needed resources are on the page, anyway).

Can anyone please explain how this is done? Does it have anything to do with renaming a link?

If it's server-side coding (which I think it is), I use PHP. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are looking for URL rewriting. If you want a specific answer, add what server you are on (Apache / IIS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll use URL re-writing with mod_rewrite. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 1):

In order for those links to be mapped to your PHP scripts, you need [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) (Assuming you are on Apache)

The [http header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17) called `Content-Type` tells the browser how to interpret the data. If it is set to `text/html`, it will render as a webpage.

In PHP, you can use the [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html");
```

Similarly, you can have a PHP script output an image:

```
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
```

This type definition is called *MIME Type*.

Comment: I think this is a bit of a red herring - if you return a .jpg with text/html content type it won't show you what the OP is asking about. URL rewriting seems more on track with the original question

Comment: @user519575 I agree with you.

Comment: @afaolek, @user519575: I thought people valued answers that would go a bit beyond the scope of the question, providing more insight. After all, the mod_rewrite reference is there as well...

Comment: Thanks, anyway. It just seems a bit away from the question.

Comment: I don't think so, of course, you don't have to send the header explicitely in the  `text/html` case, but that's what makes the browser understand, that it is actually a webpage. The browser will not look at ".jpg" and think, "Oh, that's probably an image", but it will look at `Content-Type`. mod_rewrite has nothing do do with the browser displaying it as HTML, it's about the server doing a different lookup behind the scenes.